# NLog default-target-parameters from Xml configuration are not applied to programmatically added file targets

Tags: nlog

I'm working on .Net Core 2.0 console application. NLog version 4.5.7.
Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <nlog
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    throwExceptions="false"
    internalLogFile="Logs/Internal/log.txt"
    internalLogLevel="Warn"
    internalLogToConsole="false"
    internalLogToConsoleError="false"
    internalLogToTrace="false"
    internalLogIncludeTimestamp="true">

    <targets>
      <default-wrapper
        xsi:type="AsyncWrapper"
        timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0"
        overflowAction="Block"/>

      <default-target-parameters
        xsi:type="File" 
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}
          ${onexception:${newline}}${exception:format=tostring}"
        archiveAboveSize="10485760"
        maxArchiveFiles="10"
        archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
        archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
        keepFileOpen="true"
        cleanupFileName="false"/>

      <target
        name="driver"
        xsi:type="File"
        archiveFileName="Logs/Driver/Archives/log.{#####}.txt"
        fileName="Logs/Driver/log.txt"/>
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger
        name="driver"
        minlevel="Trace"
        writeTo="driver"/>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

I'm setting this config on startup of my application:

```
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(<path>, false);
```

And then I'm adding file targets to this configuration programmatically:

```
string
  deviceTag = string.Concat("Device_", _id.ToString()),
  loggerName = string.Concat("logger_", deviceTag);

LogManager.Configuration.AddRuleForAllLevels(
  new FileTarget(string.Concat("target_", deviceTag))
  {
    FileName = string.Concat("Logs/", deviceTag, "/log.txt"),
    ArchiveFileName = string.Concat("Logs/", deviceTag,
      "/Archives/log.{#####}.txt")
  }, loggerName);

_logger = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Target is working, logs are written. But default-target-parameters from xml config are ignored.
This is a bug or a feature?
Or I do something wrong?

Comment: `default-target-parameters` is a feature for the config-file-reader, that is used while reading the config-file. After the config-file is loaded, the default values are no longer used.

Comment: @Rolf, thanks for explaining.
It's awkward to hardcode log settings. But it seems I have not choice.